# Unique constraint on 2 columns on condition of value in third column in Oracle

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, unique-constraint

I need the combination of the values of two columns (X and Y) to be unique, but only if a third column ('STATUS') has a certain value. If the third column has a different value than duplicates in the first two columns are allowed.

All 3 columns are non-nullable.

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX MY_UK ON MY_TABLE(X, Y, (CASE WHEN STATUS = 'ACTIVE' THEN STATUS ELSE NULL END));
```

It complains about duplicate values which are definitely not present for records with STATUS = 'ACTIVE', I'm guessing the 'NOT_ACTIVE' STATUS or something else collides. Does anyone know a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, perhaps?

Sample table:

```
SQL> -- status = ACTIVE    : X and Y have to be unique
SQL> --          NOT_ACTIVE: X and Y don't have to be unique
SQL> create table test (x, y, status) as
  2    select 1, 1, 'NOT_ACTIVE' from dual union all
  3    select 2, 3, 'ACTIVE'     from dual;

Table created.
```

Index *concatenates* `x` and `y` with a character that doesn't exist in neither of these columns. Why? So that we'd avoid false positives; for example, `12||3` is equal as `1||23`, and we want to avoid that:

```
SQL> create unique index ui1_test on test
  2    (case when status = 'ACTIVE' then x ||'-'|| y
  3          else null
  4     end);

Index created.
```

Testing:

This row doesn't exist yet so it should be allowed:

```
SQL> insert into test (x, y, status) values (5, 6, 'ACTIVE');

1 row created.
```

The same goes for this one - doesn't exist, can be inserted:

```
SQL> insert into test (x, y, status) values (1, 1, 'NOT_ACTIVE');

1 row created.
```

Such a row already exists so you can't insert it:

```
SQL> insert into test (x, y, status) values (2, 3, 'ACTIVE');
insert into test (x, y, status) values (2, 3, 'ACTIVE')
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00001: unique constraint (SCOTT.UI1_TEST) violated
```

Values similar to previous insert (`x` and `y` exist in table, but status is now changed so row can be inserted):

```
SQL> insert into test (x, y, status) values (2, 3, 'NOT_ACTIVE');

1 row created.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

2 options (one based on @Littlefoot's answer):

Unique index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX MY_UK_IX ON MY_TABLE (CASE "STATUS" WHEN 'V' THEN NULL ELSE TO_CHAR("X")||'^'||TO_CHAR("Y") END);
```

Virtual column with a normal unique constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE ADD (X_Y_UK VARCHAR2(100) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (CASE WHEN STATUS = 'V' THEN NULL ELSE (X||'^'||Y) END))
ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE ADD CONSTRAINT CHECK_X_Y_UK UNIQUE (X_Y_UK)
```